# Completing a logical transformation.

Tags: propositional-calculus, boolean-algebra

So I have a problem where I need to solve the first part of an implication so that it works with the second part.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xx5bE.jpg
This is the problem as given to me.

What i have gotten up to now is this:
(P ∧ Q → P) → ((P ∧ Q) ∨ R → P ∨ R)
←
P ∨ R → S

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LbEax.jpg
The three laws that are use are included on this page.
I have checked with prover9/mace4 and this transformation is valid, but I am unsure if it is actually the correct transformation.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your task correctly.

(EDIT: Apparently I *really* didn't - see comments)

Anyway, I made some substitutions using the definitions given in your first link:

1. $(p \wedge q) \wedge p \rightarrow (p \wedge q)$
2. $(p \wedge q) \rightarrow p \rightarrow ((p \wedge q) \vee r \rightarrow p \vee r)$
3. $(((p \wedge q) \vee r) \rightarrow (p \vee r)) \rightarrow (((p \vee r) \rightarrow s) \rightarrow (((p \wedge q) \vee r)\rightarrow s))$

Using those substitutions as assumptions, we could continue transforming as follows:

4. $(((p \wedge q) \wedge p ) \vee r) \rightarrow ((p \wedge q) \vee r)$ (1, **4.5**)
5. $((p \wedge q) \vee r) \rightarrow ((p \wedge q) \vee r)$ (4, **3.92b**)
6. $((p \wedge q) \vee r) \rightarrow (p \vee r)$ (5, **3.92b**)
7. $((p \vee r) \rightarrow s) \rightarrow (((p \wedge q) \vee r) \rightarrow s)$ (3, 6, **3.93**)
8. $((p \wedge q) \vee r) \rightarrow (p \vee r)$ (5, 6, **3.99a**)
9. $((p \vee r) \rightarrow s) \rightarrow ((p \vee r) \rightarrow s)$ (7, 8, **3.93**)

...here's where it's me who gets stuck. What are the "Métathéorème" hiding at **3.100**? Are you by any chance allowed to use $(p \rightarrow p) \rightarrow p$ ?

Comment: basically, i am told that the result of the transformation is the bottom. Using the three rules given, I have to figure out how the implication works between the two formulas. https://imgur.com/a/0ZVog   This is a simple example of how it works.

Comment: Oh. So the part of your problem written down in angle brackets is already part of the transformation and not what you should arrive at at the top. And you may *only* use the three rules in the transformation?

Comment: yeah. The angle brackets are telling me what transformations are used and from that I have to find what the top part of the problem is so that I can go from the top part to the bottom using the rules in the brackets. Basically, I have to deduce from the information given to me what the starting equation is.

Comment: How did you arrive at $(p \vee r) \rightarrow s$, if I may ask? All I am getting is $((p \vee r) \rightarrow s) \rightarrow ((p \wedge q) \vee r \rightarrow s)$.

Comment: I did not personally get to that, i was just re-writing the bottom part of the problem. I also got to the answer that you have gotten and I believe that it is the correct answer.